# How can I get the generic information of class using BCEL?

Tags: generics, bytecode, bcel

I would like to get the generic information (**Counter** class) of my CounterPersistence class using BCEL 6.0-SNAPSHOT. The signature is like this:

```
public interface CounterPersistence extends BasePersistence<Counter> {
....
}
```

I'm using the following code to read the bytecode

```
JavaClass javaClass = ...;
Attribute[] attributes = javaClass.getAttributes();
for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
    if (attribute instanceof Signature) {
        Signature signature = (Signature) attribute;
        //put the code here that get the Counter class from the signature
    }
}
```

But I'm failing to write a code that parse the signature and allow me to get the type Counter.
  Thoughts?

Comment: The above code gives me the `Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/liferay/portal/service/persistence/BasePersistence<Lcom/liferay/counter/model/Counter;>;` signature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BCEL utilities from FindBugs, e.g. [GenericUtilities.getTypeParameters(...)](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/api/edu/umd/cs/findbugs/ba/generic/GenericUtilities.html#getTypeParameters%28java.lang.String%29) method or better switch to [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) framework.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
Class.forName(org.apache.bcel.classfile.Utility.methodSignatureArgumentTypes("(" + signature + ")V")[0]);
```